# Identifying a specific index in a list of strings and removing everything in the list beyond that index in Haskell

Tags: string, list, haskell, indexing, split

I've recently started learning haskell, and I've encountered this problem which I can't seem to overcome.

My input is a list of strings which contain 3 characters each. What I want to do is split the list at a certain point and have the output be the list up until that point.

Example:

```
Main> listsplitter ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "STP", "DDD"]
Main> ["AAA", "BBB", "CCC"]
Main> listsplitter ["AAA", "STP", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"]
Main> ["AAA"]
```

Where STP in this case is the identifying string at which to stop the output string.

If it's possible to split a string in a similar way, or perhaps even easier, that would also be useful. As this list of strings is further up the problem I'm working on a string. Like this:

```
Main> stringsplitter "AAABBBCCCSTPDDD
Main> "AAABBBCCC"
Main> stringsplitter "AAASTPBBBCCCDDD"
Main> "AAA"
```

I should also mention that I would like to achieve this *without* importing data modules.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Unless this happens to be an exercise that asks you to write the recursive algorithm explicitly, you are looking for `takeWhile`.

Comment: Ah! Thank you! That is exactly what I was looking for. Can't believe I didn't find that on my own. Oh well.

Comment: Check out hoogle and other things that are mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your first question has two parts:

1. finding the [`takeWhile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile) function
2. Writing a predicate to use with `takeWhile`, once you've found it

For (1), you could try searching Hoogle for something like `[a] -> [a]`, which is not the full type signature you want but is a part of it, and then scrolling through matches; you will find `takeWhile` before long.

For (2) you clearly want something involving `(==)` or perhaps `(/=)`. Playing around with that a bit you may come up with:

```
keep :: String -> Bool
keep x = x /= "STP"
```

And you can simplify that by using partial application instead:

```
keep :: String -> Bool
keep = (/= "STP")
```

Finally you just combine parts (1) and (2):

```
listSplitter :: [String] -> [String]
listSplitter = takeWhile (/= "STP")
```

To solve the second problem, that of `stringSplitter`, you can't simply use `takeWhile`, because it can only look at one item at a time, and you need to look at more. There is probably an elegant way to do this using something from `Data.List` and/or `Data.List.Split` (exercise: find an elegant way), but it is also quite easy to implement yourself recursively with pattern matching starting from the head of the list:

```
stringSplitter :: String -> String
stringSplitter [] = []
stringSplitter ('S':'T':'P':_) = []
stringSplitter (x:xs) = x : stringSplitter xs
```